# Ruby net-ping usage confusion

Tags: ruby, ping

I'm trying to figure out how to use the `net/ping` gem and I have a couple of questions since I've been using it:

- Why do you need admin privileges to run `ICMP`
- Does it return true or false? For example:

  ```
  Net::Ping::ICMP.new("127.0.0.1").ping?# <= true 

  #So I could do something like this:
  ping = Net::Ping::ICMP.new("127.0.0.1") 
  if ping == true
    puts "true"
  else
    puts "This shouldn't run"
  end
  #<= true

  #or does it return packets received?
  #so I could do something like this:

  ping = Net::Ping::ICMP.new("127.0.0.1")ping?
  if ping =~ /Received = 1/
    puts "true"
  else
    puts "This shouldn't run"
  end
  #<= true
  ```

I'm confused and I can't seem to find anything on google pertaining to how it works: https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&btnG=Search&q=ruby+net%3A%3Aping%3A%3Aicmp+tutorial

If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how ruby evals `if`:

```
irb> ping = true
 => true 
irb > ping =~ /Received = 1/
 => nil 
irb> nil ? "NIL is true" : "NIL is not true"
 => "NIL is not true"
```

Result of match `true` is `nil`, and `if nil` is false. So, your second example will always outputs "true" (even if `.ping?` will be `false`).

And 'admin privileges': you cannot create ICMP packet as normal user. Unless you use `/bin/ping` which is SUID. (which `net/ping` gem don't use). `.

Comment: That's great and all but that's not what I asked